# how to scroll list of uiviews in a UIScrollView which will be in bottom of the page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i want to place a list of uiviews instead of uiimageviews as a content in uiscrollview for my ipad app.i got images scrolling by using imageviews, but i need uiviews as  a list of  subviews that has to be scroll horizontally?i tried adding uiviews in uiscrollview through Interfacebuilder ,but while running the app  i can see only one uiview where as all remaining views are not there. please help me out of this.

---

I tried it like that, still it's not showing the view, and also I tried programmatically for dimensions of `UIScrollView` and views inside it like the the code as below: –

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 604, 728,365);
scrollView.bounces = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


UIView *subView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 604, 758,365)];
subView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[scrollView addSubview:subView1];
[subView1 release];
UIView *subView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(828, 604, 758,365)];
subView2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[scrollView addSubview:subView2];
[subView2 release];
[scrollView release];
```

Comment: have you set the content size of it, i think you increase the scroll view size in interfacebuilder,  give the contentsize more then scroll view, for example if you interfacebuilder scroll view size is (0,0,600,460) , then give scroll view content size in viewdid load like this cgsizemake(900,460) it will work

Comment: if still not seeing remaining view then tell me

Comment: ya i tried like that still its not showing the view. and also i tried programatically for dimensions of scroll view and views inside it like the the code below:

Comment: scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 604, 728,365);
 scrollView.bounces = YES;
 scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
 scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
 scrollView.delegate = self;
 scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
 scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: UIView *subView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 604, 758,365)];
 subView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
 [scrollView addSubview:subView1];
 [subView1 release];
 UIView *subView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(828, 604, 758,365)];
 subView2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
 [scrollView addSubview:subView2];
 [subView2 release];
 [scrollView release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add UIView as an when needed. you need to use programmatic approach to add UIView. You should have a look at PageControl sample code provided by Apple. I hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *subView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 604, 758,365)];
subView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[scrollView addSubview:subView1];
[subView1 release];
UIView *subView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(828, 604, 758,365)];
subView2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[scrollView addSubview:subView2];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(758+758, 365+365)]]
[subView2 release];
[scrollView release];
```

**[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(758+758, 365+365)]]**

you need to set the contentsize to be able to scroll and see all subviews.

Comment: ya boss i did that and its showing now, but its not scrolling horizontally, it is  in diagnoll scrolling.

Comment: [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(758, 365+365)]]
 try with this

Comment: i tried with [758+758,365]; . now it is scrolling horizontally but only first view i can see. second view is not coming

Answer (score 0):

i tried with [758+758,365]; . now it is scrolling horizontally but only first view i can see. second view is not coming .

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 604, 728,365);
scrollView.bounces = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1600,365)];


UIView *subView1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 604, 758,365)];
subView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
subView1.frame=scrollView.bounds;
[subView1 addSubview:myImageView];
[scrollView addSubview:subView1];


UIView *subView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(828, 604, 758,365)];
subView2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
subView2.frame=scrollView.bounds;

[scrollView addSubview:subView2];

    [subView1 release];
[subView2 release];


[scrollView release];
```